# Cordova sqliteplugin pre-populated sqlite db with error 'cordova.exec is not a function'

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova

when I use sqliteplugin like 1st example inside of `onDeviceReady: function ()`, it works fine. But when I use like 2nd example inside controller, it's not work.

```
TypeError: cordova.exec is not a function.
```

Example 1

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app = {
// Application Constructor

initialize: function () {  

this.bindEvents();

},


bindEvents: function () {    

document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady);
},

onDeviceReady: function () {

function copyDatabaseFile(dbName) {

  var sourceFileName = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/' + dbName;
  var targetDirName = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

  return Promise.all([
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolveLocalFileSystemURL(sourceFileName, resolve, reject);
    }),
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolveLocalFileSystemURL(targetDirName, resolve, reject);
    })
  ]).then(function (files) {
    var sourceFile = files[0];
    var targetDir = files[1];
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      targetDir.getFile(dbName, {}, resolve, reject);
    }).then(function () {
      //console.log("file already copied");
    }).catch(function () {
      console.log("file doesn't exist, copying it");
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        sourceFile.copyTo(targetDir, dbName, resolve, reject);
      }).then(function () {
        console.log("database file copied");
      });
    });
  });
}

copyDatabaseFile('mydatabase.db').then(function () {
  // success! :)
  var db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('mydatabase.db');

if(window.cordova)
    db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('mydatabase.db');
else
    db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('mydatabase.db', '1','my', 1024*1024*100);


  db.readTransaction(function (txn) {
    txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM mytable', [], function (tx, res) {
      console.log('Successfully read from pre-populated DB:');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    });
  });
}).catch(function (err) {
  // error! :(
  console.log(err);
});

},

}

};

app.initialize();
```

Example 2

```
app.controller("Tab4Ctrl", function($scope) {
var db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('mydatabase.db');

if(window.cordova)
    db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('mydatabase.db');
else
    db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('mydatabase.db', '1','my', 1024*1024*100);
  db.readTransaction(function (txn) {
    txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM mytable', [], function (tx, res) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: I have added this plugins   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-sqlite-2" spec="~1.0.4" />

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake

```
app.controller("Tab4Ctrl",['$scope', function($scope, $sqliteplugin) {
   var db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('mydatabase.db');
  if(window.cordova)
       db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('mydatabase.db');
else
      db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('mydatabase.db', '1','my', 1024*1024*100);
      db.readTransaction(function (txn) {
     txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM mytable', [], function (tx, res) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
});
});
});
}])
```